# How to play private vimeo videos in android kotlin compose in Exoplayer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, vimeo-api

I got the videoresponse but how can i play it in exoplayer this is my code which successfully gets the video response

```
       authenticator.authenticateWithClientCredentials(vimeoCallback(
                onSuccess = {
                    initializePlayer()
                    val apiClient = VimeoApiClient(configuration, authenticator)
                    Log.e("DONETSK",it.data.accessToken.toString())
                    apiClient.fetchVideo(
                        uri = STAFF_PICKS_URI,
                        fieldFilter = null,
                        queryParams = null,
                        cacheControl = null,
                        callback = vimeoCallback(
                            onSuccess = {
                             //   Log.e("DONETSKerere","Success")
                            },
                            onError = {
                                Log.e("DONETSKerere","Failed")
                            }
                        )
                    )
                },
                onError = {
                }
            ))
```

This is my compose view for showing the vimeo video i want to the playable data from the above vimeo code how to do that

```
   @Composable
  fun ExoPlaya(currentItem: Int, playbackPosition: Long, player: ExoPlayer?) {

Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), // Occupy the max size in the Compose UI tree
        factory = { context ->
            PlayerView(context).also{
                val uri = "uri"
                //

                val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri)
                it.player = player
                it.player?.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
                it.player?.playWhenReady
                it.player?.seekTo(currentItem,playbackPosition)
                it.player?.prepare()
                it.player?.play()
            }
        },
        update = { view ->
        }
    )
}
}
```